# How to show Zeros when a decimal is converted to string?

Tags: c#, string, decimal

I have several decimal numbers that I need to show as strings (no need for decimal places). I use the following code:

```
mytextblock.text= mydecimalnumber.ToString("#");
```

However this code will show nothing if the number is 0. I need to display a "0" instead of an empty string. I can do this using if and else but I don't think this is the best solution to do with many decimal variables.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: [The "#" Custom Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#SpecifierD)

Answer (score 0):

Some user "David.." posted this answer and it worked for me but then he deleted it later:

He mentioned that `ToString("#")` will only show digits that are not `zeros`.

In order to default to `0`, I should use `ToString("0")`